# 1996 ford contour bank 1 02 wiring problem

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a 1996 ford contour 2.5 v6 that my dog pulled the wiring and plug off of  the 02 sensor.the wires off the harness are this brown w/blue stripe.black w/orange stripe..white w/green stripe.and solid purple....my new plug is this black.orange/with yellow stripe..black w/white stripe..i read one post here about a yucon..but it help with mine...any help with this problem i would be very grateful...i need to know both how the original wiring was connected, and how to go about connecting to the new sensor.

Comment: What is the question? Are you looking to find out what the correct wiring was? Or are you concerned the new plug has different order of wires? I cannot tell from your post.

Comment: The OP seems to say that the car's wiring harness offers four wires to the sensor, while the replacement sensor has only two wires. I think the wrong replacement sensor is being used.